# Non-decaying property of Yogi body after death

Tags: scripture, history, yoga, body

It is well-known that the body of Paramahamsa Yogananda, after his death, did not decay like any other dead body. And we can read it from [here](http://oaks.nvg.org/yogananda_mortuary_report.pdf).

Are there any other instances from either history or scriptures similar to this?

Comment: Because of two statements in Rowe's letter, some have questioned whether the term "incorruptibility" is appropriate. First, in his fourth paragraph he wrote: "For protection of the public health, embalming is desirable if a dead body is to be exposed for several days to public view. Embalming of the body of Paramhansa Yogananda took place twenty-four hours after his demise." In the eleventh paragraph he wrote: "On the late morning of March 26th, we observed a very slight, a barely noticeable, change – the appearance on the tip of the nose of a brown spot, about one-fourth inch in diameter.

Comment: This small faint spot indicated that the process of desiccation (drying up) might finally be starting. No visible mold appeared however." So the wiki page shows some very questionable findings.

Comment: Embalming was done on his body.